# Why was this question removed due to moderation reasons

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I am trying to understand the reason why [Bounty Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272233/bounty-questions) was removed from Meta Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation.

**Actual Question:**

> I have found a bug in the bounty being awarded automatically. I had set a bounty to one of my own questions, but then found a solution to the question myself after a day or two.
>
> After posting the answer to my own question, and getting awarded the Self-Learner badge, the bounty on that question was lost, as no-one else gave any more answers to that question in particlar.
>
> Should the bounty be lost in these cases? I propose the bounty to be awarded to myself, as I found the answer to that question. After all, the rep for that bounty was taken from my own rep. It is only fair that the rep is not lost

I guess OP didn't remove it otherwise the page would have mentioned: *This question was voluntarily removed by its author*. OP still has a valid account on the site, so that could not be a reason either.

Comment: In the end it was a lack of understanding how the bounty system works. That is already explained in the help-centre - there is no need to keep the question around IMO.

Comment: @vba4all I guess dupes dont get deleted. _Not sure if this is still valid: [How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)_

Comment: @AzizShaikh Not all duplicates are automatically better.  Some duplicates can add value, but many of them don't.  The question needs to actually use radically different terminology to actually add value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question OP requested it be deleted.

A moderator respected that request.

Comment: Makes sense. OP couldn't delete it as it had an answer. Thanks.

Comment: in cases like this, it makes sense for moderator to add an explanation for 10Kers, like "This question was deleted by request of the author." ([example where this was done](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/207914/is-programming-experience-education-important-for-qa-developers-engineers#comment414149_207914 "10K link at Programmers"))